# how to find last user logged in web application using servlet's web.xml

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml

is it possible to show the previous username to the current user loggedin in jsp-servlet web application only with the help of web.xml, if yes then how.

i have a jsp-servlet based web application , i want to show the previous last user logged in the website (for eg. userA) to the current user (for eq: userB).

eg:
 userA login time = 00:00:10
 userA logout time = 00:05:10
now userB loggedin
and i want to show the welcome page as "Hello userB, last User was userA"
only with the help of web.xml

Comment: *"is it possible.."* ..you could find your shift key and apply it to the start of sentences?  Trying to read all lower case is like trying to listen to someone mumbling.

Comment: You may implement a filter to meet this requirement, filter will intercept the request and can log the info that you need. You'll need to write a filter, however you'll not need to touch your existing code.

Comment: Using only web.xml ? Imposhibru

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson i will remember from nxt time

Comment: @sudmong but how i will store the last visitor using filter

Comment: You may store the info in DB/file whenever a user logs into the system. If you only need the last user then whenever a user enters delete the old entry and store the new one.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible. You will have to somehow keep track of logged in users in the http session or in a backing database.